# What is the proper AND operator in SQLite where statement

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, lambda

Using  &  or  && in the where-statement? It seems it is not working.

can anyone help me with the Lambda expression on Sqlite query statement.

Thanks.

```
var existingItemUoM = db2.Table().Where(c => c.UoM == ItemNo & c.ItemNo == CodeforUoM).SingleOrDefault()
```

Comment: What framework/language is this? [tag:sqlite] is an SQL engine but your question is not about [tag:SQL]!

Comment: I was trying to use Lambda on SQLite and I was not sure to use AND or & or && in the Query statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to be using linq, the correct operator for `AND` is

```
&&
```

A good reference here are the [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b).
The single `&` is a non-short-circuit and-operator. This means even if the first condition evaluates to true, the second condition will be checked (which isn't the case when using `&&`, the short-circuit and-operator).

Furthermore, in a real SQLite statement the correct expression for the boolean and-operator would be `and`, refer to [the expressions of SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html).

Comment: Single [`&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c(v=vs.90).aspx) applied to boolean values in a non-short-circuiting AND, not a binary operator.

Comment: @DStanley thanks for the remark, you're right... it was too early when i wrote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Correct operator for AND is &&, check with following where class

var existingItemUoM = db2.Table().Where(**(c => c.UoM) && (c.UoM == ItemNo) && (c.ItemNo == CodeforUoM)**).SingleOrDefault()